# how to get a key for encryption in AWS KMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

I decide to manage my key use AWS KMS.

I made a key at "Customer managed keys" and imported my key (symmetric key).

I tried to use key that imported to kms in my python application using boto3. but there was no way to receive uncoded my key.

What should I to get plain text of key. I wonder how to get uncoded key that i uploded to aws kms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't get private key** from KMS. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html):

> You cannot extract, export, view, or manage this key material.

Since you've imported the key yourself, you must **use your own copy**.